# quartz scheduler: run on last day of the month and few other days

Tags: java, cron, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I want to run a job on the 3rd and last day of a month.

Is the following cron expression correct ?

"0 0 3 3,L * * ?"

When I try it in www.cronmaker.com it says it's an invalid expression.

The main point of this question is if I can use "L" (representing the last day of month with other days)

If not, how can I express it using Cron ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct format should be

```
0 0 0 3,L * ? *
```

but as you correctly state cromaker.com does not seem to be it.

If you used two crons

0 0 0 3 * ? *
0 0 0 L * ? *

it would work

Comment: Is it only cronmaker that doesn't support it ? or generally it's not supported by cron ? unfortunately I couldn't find it any example of doing so online.

Comment: Quartz uses its own format, but cronmaker.com reports that its uses Quartz - The real question is `does it work in your app`?

Comment: is it possible to have `0 0 0 3,L * MON *` also?